# Does shared_ptr a = make_shared() create a copy of the shared_ptr before constructor is run?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, thread-safety, shared-ptr

This might be a stupid question.

Let's say we're in C++11 land and we use make_shared() to create a smart pointer. We then use this smart pointer to initialize a variable with like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<class> = make_shared(/* args to c'tor of class*/ );
```

Now I know two things:

1. Assignement is not initialization. In this case we have initialisation. This would mean in the above case probably the copy constructor is called for the `shared_ptr` which is returned by `make_shared`.
2. Copy elision is only mandatory in C++17.

Does this mean that on every instance of make_shared a temporary copy of the shared_ptr is created and inserted into the copy constructor? Because this would mean for thread safety that a lock would have to be taken across the initialisation in case other threads preempt the thread and call shared_ptr::use_count() member function?

Comment: "*Because this would mean for thread safety*" There is no question of "thread safety" because no other thread could possibly interfere in this process. Any temporary is local to this thread and cannot be accessed. And if you're initializing an object accessible to other threads, you *cannot* access that object from another thread until it has been properly *initialized*. This is true of *any* object. Until the full initialization has executed (and any required synchronization is done to make it available to other threads), you cannot access the object from some other thread.

Comment: @NicolBolas: You're right I got confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things to avoid the copy:

- 1 is the compiler's RVO (return value optimization);
- 2 is the move constructor/assignment.

for code `auto foo = std::make_shared<Foo>();`
RVO will create the object directly on the stack. and even we disable the RVO by `-fno-elide-constructors`, the move constructor will try used as the returned object from `make_shared` is a temporary one.

Below is a simple test code. (this code only show the concept but not for a real-world shared_ptr implementation)

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct my_shared_ptr
{
    T *t_{nullptr};

    my_shared_ptr(T *t): t_(t) {
        std::cout << "constructor" << std::endl;
    };

    my_shared_ptr(const my_shared_ptr<T>&) {
        std::cout << "copy" << std::endl;
    }

    my_shared_ptr<T>& operator=(const my_shared_ptr<T>&) {
        std::cout << "copy" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }

#ifndef NO_MOVE
    my_shared_ptr(my_shared_ptr<T>&&) {
        std::cout << "move" << std::endl;
    }

    my_shared_ptr<T>& operator=(my_shared_ptr<T>&&) {
        std::cout << "move" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
#endif
};

template <typename T>
my_shared_ptr<T>
my_make_shared() {
    return my_shared_ptr<T>(new T);
}

struct Foo {};

int main()
{
    auto foo = my_make_shared<Foo>();
    return 0;
}
```

Condition 1, compile with c++11 shows:

```
$ g++ a.cc -std=c++11 ; ./a.out
constructor
```

Condition 2, compile with c++11/disable RVO shows:

```
$ g++ a.cc -std=c++11 -fno-elide-constructors ; ./a.out
constructor
move
move
```

Condition 3, compile with c++11/disable RVO/no move shows:

```
$ g++ a.cc -std=c++11 -fno-elide-constructors -DNO_MOVE ; ./a.out
constructor
copy
copy
```

Comment: "*avoid the copy assignment*" Copy *assignment* is never "avoided". Only copy construction can be "avoided".

Comment: Thanks for the comments, maybe `avoid copy` is more appropriate here